# How to Render an Angular routerLink inside the cell of an ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

The link I am trying to render looks like this when I just try to render it on a basic HTML page:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/leverance/detail', 13]">A new link</a>
```

When trying to render it on the ag-Grid, I try to do like below:

src\app\leverancer\leverancer.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataGridColumnDefs = [
          { 
            headerName: 'Type', 
            field: 'leveranceType.name', 
            width: 150,
            cellRenderer: this.customCellRendererFunc       
          }
    ];
}

customCellRendererFunc(params): string {
  const cellContent `<a [routerLink]="['/leverance/detail', 13]">A new link</a>`;
  return cellContent;
}
```

but I don't see a working routerLink in my ag-Grid.
Can you tell me what I need to do to render a working routerLink in my ag-Grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `cellRenderer` only supports normal HTML (without any angular-specific stuff).

You want to use `cellRendererFramework` as seen in these examples:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular2-support/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-more-complex-angular-components

Since you use RouterLink, you probably need `RouterModule` in the `moduleImports`

Comment: Thank you for your tip :) I have found a resource by Michael Karén, where, apparently, he uses cellRendererFramework and makes a RouterLinkRendererComponent:
https://medium.com/ag-grid/enhance-your-angular-grid-reports-with-formatted-values-and-links-34fa57ca2952
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-ag-grid?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic component that is usable for any link cell.

Usage

```ts
columnDefs = [
  {
    colId: 'My Column',
    cellRendererFramework: AgGridLinkCellComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      // `text` and `link` both accept either an string expression (same as `field`) or a function that gets ICellRendererParams
      text: 'title',
      link: (params: ICellRendererParams) => `/my-path/${_.get(params, 'data.id')}`
    }
  }
]
```

Register the component in your `AppModule`:

```ts
imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([
      AgGridLinkCellComponent
    ])
]
```

The component itself:

```ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AgRendererComponent} from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {ICellRendererParams} from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ag-grid-link-cell-component',
  template: '<a [routerLink]="link">{{ text }}</a>',
})
export class AgGridLinkCellComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  link: string;
  text: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.refresh(params);
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    const dataParams = params.colDef.cellRendererParams;
    this.link = _.isFunction(dataParams.link) ? dataParams.link(params) : _.get(params.data, dataParams.link);
    this.text = _.isFunction(dataParams.text) ? dataParams.link(params) : _.get(params.data, dataParams.text);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution. I tried it with **angular 7** and its work fine for me.

ag grid provides events and callbacks **onCellClicked** and **cellRendere** are two of them.

problem with onCellCliecked and cellRendere is that they work on JS. so the **this** object associated with these callbacks will be a JS instance.

But for angular to call functions or route any url we'll be need of instance of angular component which no available in those callbacks

so Here is solution to get that angular instance to work with component.

Typescript stores instance of current object in **_this** whenever **this** is not available.
we can get instance of angular component by

```
const self = eval('_this');
```

this **self** will hold instance of angular component so we can call any function or service from angular component and also we can `self.router.navigateByUrl(url)`

here is example

```
{field: 'plan', headerName: 'Plan Case', sortable:true,filter:true,
  cellRenderer:function(paramObj){
    //for making cell as link
    return `<a href="javascript:void(0)" >Plan Case</a>`;
  }, 
  onCellClicked:function(data){
    const self = eval('_this');
    //navigating on clicking on cell
    self.router.navigateByUrl('YOUR_URL');
  }  
},
```

Alternatively you can call any angular function from **onCellClicked** event. example

```
onCellClicked:function(data){
        const self = eval('_this');
        //calling test function from angular component.
        self.test(data.data);
      }
```

Thanks